# How to embed native OpenGL content in Java AWT on Mac OS

Tags: macos, opengl, awt

I want to display some 3d objects in an AWT frame on Mac OS. However I would like to do this drawing natively. Can somebody please provide with some resources to do this? I have searched a lot and could nt find any except the example http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/JAWTExample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000683 on the Apple developer site which is for Mac OS 10.6 and higher. But I have a 10.5.8 and also the example is a bit complicated with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous.  Do you mean you want to use a library that calls OpenGL to make it render quickly? You probably want JOGL which supports Mac OS X.

- [JOGL website](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www)
- [JOGL downloads](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/deployment/JOGL-DEPLOYMENT.html).
- [A decent JOGL setup tutorial](http://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-1)